# Vue 3 access 'this' properties ($router, $store, ...)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I have been working with a framework, used by the company where I work, which uses vue; I'm a PHP programmer, so I don't know js deeply.

Usually, when I want to log the vuex store within a view, I just need to do the following line of code:

```
console.log(this.$store);
```

Lately I started to like the vue and started my own little project to practice, but when I tried the code above it didn't work and when I logged the 'this' object it gave me the following result:

```
console.log(this);
```

[image]

I can access the activeTab property but i can't access any of the other properties.

How can i access the $store property?

Vue full code:

```
<template>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <article :class="{ active: activeTab === 'Perfil' }" @click.prevent="activeTab = 'Perfil'" :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + require('@/assets/icons/perfil.svg') + ')' }" ></article>
      <article :class="{ active: activeTab === 'Work' }" @click.prevent="activeTab = 'Work'" :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + require('@/assets/icons/work.svg') + ')' }"></article>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'Vue';

  export default ({
    data() {
      return {
      }
    },
    computed: {
      activeTab() {
        console.log(this);
        return null;
        //return this.$store.state.activeTab;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you installed Vuex and created a store?

Comment: yes, i installed it with the vue cli, it is in a ts file

import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    activeTab: 'Perfil'
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem with Vue 3 + Vuex 4.  In your screenshot, it shows the `$store` property on `this`.  Can you create a https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: did you setup the project using typescript

Comment: yes, i did. I set it to class format, i started a new one without the class thing and it is working.